# Translating to Fortran a C code with structure containing pointer and unions containing pointers

Tags: c, windows, fortran, unions, xll

I am delving in the Excel XLL SDK, a C API allowing to compile C DLLs (called XLLs) that are directly referenceable in Excel, and that then allow Excel to directly call the C functions. (Naturally, the functions have to obey to certains rules etc.)

I want to rewrite this API in Fortran. The API use a small number of basic Windows types (that are defined in headers that `Windows.h` includes) that are just `typedef`s of basic type (it's almost code obfuscation !) :

- `WORD` is a typedef for `unsigned short`
- `INT23` is a typedef for `signed int` = `int`
- `DWORD_PTR` is an `unsigned __int64` = `long long`
- `BYTE` is an `unsigned char`
- `LPSTR` is null terminated `char*`

These type translate to Fortran as follows :

- `logical*2`
- `integer*4`
- `integer*8`
- `logical*1`
- array of single `character`'s (trailing `\0` handling left to the user)

Then very simple `struct`s are defined, for instance :

```
typedef struct xlmref12
{
    WORD count;
    XLREF12 reftbl[1];                  /* actually reftbl[count] */
} XLMREF12, *LPXLMREF12;
```

which already poses the question of how to translate to fortran a C pointer for Fortran. (Answer, as far as I have been told : `C_PTR (from ISO_C_BINDING)`.)

But then, more complicated structures are defined, relying on unions containing pointers, for instance :

```
typedef struct xloper 
{
    union 
    {
        double num;                 /* xltypeNum */
        LPSTR str;                  /* xltypeStr */
#ifdef __cplusplus
        WORD xbool;                 /* xltypeBool */
#else   
        WORD bool;                  /* xltypeBool */
#endif  
        WORD err;                   /* xltypeErr */
        short int w;                    /* xltypeInt */
        struct 
        {
            WORD count;             /* always = 1 */
            XLREF ref;
        } sref;                     /* xltypeSRef */
        struct 
        {
            XLMREF *lpmref;
            IDSHEET idSheet;
        } mref;                     /* xltypeRef */
        struct 
        {
            struct xloper *lparray;
            WORD rows;
            WORD columns;
        } array;                    /* xltypeMulti */
        struct 
        {
            union
            {
                short int level;        /* xlflowRestart */
                short int tbctrl;       /* xlflowPause */
                IDSHEET idSheet;        /* xlflowGoto */
            } valflow;
            WORD rw;                /* xlflowGoto */
            BYTE col;               /* xlflowGoto */
            BYTE xlflow;
        } flow;                     /* xltypeFlow */
        struct
        {
            union
            {
                BYTE *lpbData;          /* data passed to XL */
                HANDLE hdata;           /* data returned from XL */
            } h;
            long cbData;
        } bigdata;                  /* xltypeBigData */
    } val;
    WORD xltype;
} XLOPER, *LPXLOPER;
```

We have structures in Fortran, fine, union (with maps) also, but problem : unions cannot contain anything allocatable, nor pointer.

*How could I circumvent this issue ?*

*Remark* : in fact, I want to recode (if possible) in Fortran the header `XLCALL.H` and source `XLCALL.CPP` from Excel XLL SDK completely to be able to designe Fortran XLLs entirely in Fortran. (I could wrap Fortran code in C and use the Excel XLL SDK but that's not what I have been tasked with ...) For sake of completeness I give the `XLCALL.H` and `XLCALL.CPP` codes beneath.

[`XLCALL.H`](https://github.com/keithalewis/xll12/blob/master/xll/XLCALL.H)

[`XLCALL.CPP`](https://github.com/keithalewis/xll12/blob/master/xll/XLCALL.CPP)

Comment: I have read your entire question, and have two questions and an observation. What? Why? And better you than me.

Comment: Not quite sure where to start. Maybe with we don't have unions in standard Fortran. There might be non-standard vendor extensions supported by your compiler, but they won't be portable and lord knows how they work with ISO_C_BINDING.

Comment: @IanBush I am using last Intel Fortran compiler. We have unions but they can't contain allocatable stuff nor pointer (see the norm) so the question would be : is there a type that would achieve the union pattern while allowing for allocatable stuff and pointers ?

Comment: But why does it matter what language an API is implemented in? Can you actually invoke it from fortran? That is, can you invoke the existing API with ISO_C_BINDING? And if so, why do you need to port it? And if not, what do you hope to accomplish? Basically, what do you mean by "I want to rewrite this API in Fortran." You want to hook into Excel with Fortran, even though it only has a C API?